# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CoursesController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, crud

All courses is are showing on index.html.erb and I am trying to view an individual course by clicking view more. Which should link to the show path as I understand, it display that individual course. Which is the result I need.

However, rails throughs this error on the URL http://ruby-on-rails-102039.nitrousapp.com:3000/courses/rails (within this URL rails is title of the course, the title is created with each new course.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CoursesController#show
Couldn't find Course with 'id'=rails

Extracted source (around line #7):

def show @course = Course.find(params[:id]) end
```

Course controller

```
 class CoursesController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @courses = Course.all
 end

 def show
 @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end
```

Routes

```
devise_for :users
root 'signups#new'
resources :signups, only: [:new, :create]

resources :courses

Prefix Verb   URI Pattern      Controller#Action
root GET    /   signups#new

  root GET    /                              signups#new
  signups POST   /signups(.:format)             signups#create
 new_signup GET    /signups/new(.:format)         signups#new
  courses GET    /courses(.:format)             courses#index
 POST   /courses(.:format)             courses#create
 new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)         courses#new
 edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)    courses#edit
 course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)         courses#show
 PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)         courses#update
 PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)         courses#update
 DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)         courses#destroy
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="course-index">
  <%@courses.each_slice(4) do|course| %>

    <div class ="row">
    <% course.each do |course|%>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <h3><%= course.title %></h3><br />
    <h3><%= course. description %></h3><br />

    <%= link_to 'View More', course_path(course), class:'btn btn-primary' %>
 </div>
    <%end%>
   </div>
  <%end%>
 </div>
```

Model

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :courses do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :desciption
  t.integer :course_id

  t.timestamps null: false
  end
  end
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Courses#show</h1>
<h1><%= @course.title %></h1>
<p> <%= @course.description %></p>
```

Solution: All three of these worked in the show method. I just don't understand why @course = Course.find(params[:id]). Is it because I have these columns defined in the model.

```
@course = Course.find_by(params[:title])
@course = Course.find_by(params[:course_id])
@course = Course.find_by(params[:description])
```

Comment: Can you show us how your courses table looks like, i.e. what columns did you define. I guess the migration file where you've added courses model should do fine.

Comment: You seem to have two nested each loops both defining course, did you mean to do that? I've no idea what happens,  but it looks a bit odd

Comment: @Tim  The OP is outputting the courses 4 to a row - thats why there are nested loops - the variable naming choices for the loop variables aren't great

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I was a bit tired, looking at it last night, i was worried it might overwrite something, but looking now, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`@course = Course.find(params[:id])` finds the course by the id number, but you're passing in the title instead of the id number.  If thats the way you want to keep it

```
@course = Course.find_by(title: params[:id])
```

will probably do what you want

Comment: Added your solution as the on that worked for me, with all model columns in table.  Do you know why @course = Course.find_by(title: params[:id]) does not work?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the question?  You're saying it did work for you, but then asking why it does not work?

Comment: It works when I when I removed    <h1><%= course.title %></h1> and 
 <p> <%= course.description %></p>  from show.html.erb. If want it to work with show.html.erb with course.title, course.description, I have to use the solution I posted up top.                                                                     I was saying params [:id] by itself will not work period.

Comment: It sounds like you are confused by rails routing.  If you look at the route /courses/:id(.:format)  it shows you that if you navigate to /courses/my_course - then params[:id] will be 'my_course' -- you then will need to find that in whatever column you want to look for it.    Course.find(x) will find the Course record with a primary_key column == x  (and if the primary key column is numeric it will convert x to a numeric) -  Course.find_by(...)  takes a hash and will find the record with all of those hash elements matching -- Course.find_by(title: 'abc', description:'my desc') - etc.

Comment: Also the course_id field in your model is strange naming -- Normally in rails naming that would imply a belongs_to association to another course?  The course model already has a default auto-incrmenting #id field created when you do create_table in your migration

Comment: Thanks you very much for explaining that. Course_id  does have an association with lessons that belong to that course.

Comment: umm -- if it's associated to lessons then why is it called course_id in the course table -- it should be in the lesson table/model so that you can have multiple lessons linked to a course

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
#route.rb
resources :courses, params :title
```

this route:`course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)         courses#show`

become like this:`course GET    /courses/:title(.:format)         courses#show`

```
#controller.rb

#like said Tom Walpole you can do this:
@course = Course.find_by(title: params[:title])
#but I prefer this syntax:
@course = Course.find_by_title(params[:title])
```

If you have an error, try this in the viex: `course_path(course.title)`